# Generating matrices from lists without using for loops

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of x coordinates and want to generate an array that shows the distance between each coordinate and every other coordinate, ie the first row is the distance from every coordinate to the first, the second row the the distance from every coordinate to the second etc.

I'm currently using two for loops:

`for i in range(len(x_coordinates)):
    for j in range(len(x_coordinates)):
        x_relative[i][j] = x_coordinates[j] - x_coordinates[i]`

but is there a way of doing it without iterating? Have a lot of coordinates so hoping to optimise.

Comment: If you mean the absolute distance, you can double your speed by only computing half of your matrix. The other half is symmetric if you're using `abs(coords[i]-coords[j])`.

Comment: Just noticed that you are not calculating the distance but the *difference*. The difference (sorry for the pun) is that a distance is always a positive value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `outer`, but for subtraction. Most ufuncs have an outer method built in to them:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] #your coordinates


np.subtract.outer(x,x)
array([[ 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8],
       [ 1,  0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7],
       [ 2,  1,  0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6],
       [ 3,  2,  1,  0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5],
       [ 4,  3,  2,  1,  0, -1, -2, -3, -4],
       [ 5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0, -1, -2, -3],
       [ 6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0, -1, -2],
       [ 7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0, -1],
       [ 8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe use np.subtract, that way you can have one loop instead of two, and therefore O(n) instead of O(n^2):

```
`import numpy as np
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] #your coordinates
y = np.array([np.subtract(x,i) for i in x])`
```

This results in

```
`>>> y
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
[-1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
[-2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
[-3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
[-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
[-6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2],
[-7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1],
[-8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0]])`
```